# running sql query to insert into a table and update another table

Tags: php, mysql

How do i run a sql query in php to insert into a table and update another table. for example, when an inventory is entered, and submitted, sql query should run an insert statement to update the batch file and run update statement to update the totalquantityinstock (new quantity + existing quantity) in the product table. Hope my explanation could be understood.

> Tables: Product (ProdId, Name, Cat, TtlQtyInStock,) and ProdInventory (InvID, ProdID, Qty)

Upon entering a new ProdInventory record in php form, the query should insert into ProdInventory and also update the TtlQtyInStock column in Product table).. What i want is currently the inventory of the product cld be 20, so when new inventory of 10 of same prod is added it shld sum 20 + 10.

My current query is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `ProdInventory (`ProdId`, `Quantity`) VALUES ('$ProdID', '$Quantity')";
"UPDATE product
SET QuantityInStock = (QuantityInStock + $Quantity)
WHERE ProductCode = $ProductCode";
```

I did browse thru some site but cldnt find something that suits my design. if someone cld help... :)

TIA.

Comment: Umm.. just do it? What exactly is your question about, can you clarify?

Comment: You should really read some tutorials and documentation about SQL. There is no way anyone can answer this as you have provided no relevant table structure, nor any attempts at coding the queries.

Comment: INSERT INTO TABLE1 (FIELD1) VALUES (VALUE1); UPDATE TABLE2 SET FIELD1=FIELD1+VALUE1 WHERE FIELD2=VALUE2;

Comment: So what is the problem? the only thing I can see that may cause a problem is ProductCode is used in one table while ProdId is in the other. I recommend using the same reference for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the probable solution for that though not the best is by creating an Insert Trigger. so basically what it does is everytime an insert is made in the table the trigger fires and updates the value of the stock (*it may be on the different table*)

Comment: Certainly a trigger is the way to go - but IIRC any DML within the trigger *must* be on a different table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run two update statments, instead of an insert and update.

This can be achieved in one mysql trip using stored procedures or multi_query (MYSQLi).

Here is a link for reference :

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a view. In that view you can make a column in which you can calculate anything you need. 
that way, your database structure will be very clean, and the chances of errors will reduce imho